# CreateProcess function issue

Tags: c++, .net, createprocess

I'm trying to start an process from my code with createprocess function. The command line is ok, and the other exe, i can start it without problems from visual studio.

When I am trying to start it from the other process with createprocess it gives me - Runtime error this app has requested the runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.

What could be the problem ? How could I remove this problem ?

```
        STARTUPINFO si;
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

        bool bResult;   

        ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
        si.cb = sizeof(si);
        ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

        //Cast System::String* __gc to char*
        char* chAppName = (char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(AppName);
        char* chCmdLine = (char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(CmdLine);


        //Start the child process. 
         bResult = CreateProcess( chAppName,   // No module name (use command line)
                chCmdLine,        // Command line
                NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
                NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
                FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
                0,              // No creation flags
                NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
                NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
                &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
                &pi);           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
```

Comment: Did you mean c# instead of c++?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to create the process?

Comment: I am using managed C++ (C++.NET).

Comment: It might not help, but the docs say do this: char* stringPointer = (char*) Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(managedString ).ToPointer() You don't call ToString. Don't forget to free if afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Try eliminating the `StringToHGlobalAnsi` calls and hard coding them instead first. If that stops the problems, we can then sort out the `StringToHGlobalAnsi` calls.

Comment: I have made an simple test console app, the function works fine with the cast StringToHGlobalAnsi and test app.